# Count down from 10 and repeat it when the timer has reacted 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I want to count down from 10 seconds to 0. When it have reached 0 the DIV will reload and the timer will start over again. I have this function that allows it to do exactly like I wanted but the problem is that when the countdown have reached 0 and going back to 10, it will count -1 *reload* -2 *reload* -3 *reload* -4 *reload* and so on. That is **not** how I want it! :)

Here's my code:

```
var time = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
function countdown() {
    var count = 10;
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
        $('#countdown').html(count + ' sekunder kvar');

        if(count == 0) {
            $('#weather-data').load('jquery-fetch/fetch-weatherdata.php?place=' + myplace);
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }

        count--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

How can I fix my problem so the timer counts down from 10 to 0 and repeat that countdown forever?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When this function has reached 0 for the first time and starts over, it counts like this: 10, 9, 8, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 10, 7, 6, and so on. Why does it act like this with this code?

```
function countdown() {
    var count = 10;
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
        $('#countdown').html(count + ' sekunder kvar');
        count--;

        if(count == 0) {
            $('#weather-data').load('jquery-fetch/fetch-weatherdata.php?place=' + myplace);
            clearInterval(timerId);
            countdown();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you even have `-` in a function name? :o

Comment: @nifty-dude: nope. that's illegal syntax. it'd be seen as "function count minus down()".

Comment: @NiftyDude: I added the `-` when I was writing down my question here. Didn't tested the function called `count-down` until after my question.

Comment: Why don't you just use an interval of 10 seconds?

Comment: @RobG: How can I accomplish that? As I said before, I'm new to `setInterval`

Comment: Did you see my edit? I edited my code a bit after you accepted my answer :)

Comment: I saw your edit now but I have the same problem as I talked about in my edit *pointing upwards*

Comment: @ErikEdgren Hm.. I see you are still using code before my edit, so apologize if I misunderstood you .. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a lot of problems in your script... So not sure how you even get that to work..

1. <strike>Function name can't have `-`, so that call won't work :S</strike>
2. `countdown` is a global variable inside your `function countdown()` which is the same as your function name, effectively a `countdownception`
3. You are effectively creating a new `Interval` every one second as you are calling `countdown`

To achieve what you want, try the simpler:

```
function countdown() {
    // your code goes here
    var count = 10;
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
        count--;
        console.log(count);

        if(count == 0) {
            // your code goes here
            count = 10;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xrbm5/13/

Comment: Why would you keep setting an interval and clearing it?  Each time you call it you're needless creating a new closure.  Why not just keep the interval going and reset your counter?  That way you could keep an external pointer to the interval to clear/halt if necessary.

Comment: @webnesto sorry can't get you, I only call `setInterval` once, and call `countdown()` once after `count` reaches `0`, could you clarify? :o

Comment: @webnesto yep, dawned on me exactly before your fiddle. Thanks :)

Comment: Much simpler to just use an interval of 10 seconds.

Comment: Good point RobG... I guess I assumed there was going to be some sort of visual timer if it was on 1 second intervals.

Comment: I thought there is? From OP: `$('#countdown').html(count + ' sekunder kvar');`, am I missing something? :o

Comment: Many thanks both of you but see my edit - something is wrong in my code!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at what your code is doing.

You are setting an interval to run every second. That's fine.

What isn't fine is that, every second, that interval is creating a NEW interval that individually counts down from 10.

Also, you are setting `countdown` as a global variable. So when your first counter reaches zero, it actually clears the LAST timer, leaving the first one to happily continue into negative numbers, all the while you're spawning new intervals.

Overall, it's a disaster.

Comment: Gah, after 10 seconds you'd have 10 separate timers! Though countdown isn't global, its only visible to the `count-down` function and nested scopes.

Comment: Very true! Thanks :) How should the function looks like then? I'am kinda of beginner with `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the page every 10 seconds, then:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // run some code
},10000);
```

If you want a count down, then reset just the counter at each even number of 10. The following adds start and stop functions, it re-stats from where it left off. Also, if running, clicking start doesn't start another one.

```
var weatherRefresh = (function() {
  var count = 10;
  var timerRef;
  return {
    start: function() {

      // If already running, leave it running
      if (timerRef) return;

      timerRef = setInterval(function() {
        // Display count
        document.getElementById('dislayedCount').innerHTML = count;

        if (!count--) {
          // count is zero, refresh weather info
          // and start again
          count = 10;
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    stop: function() {
      timerRef && clearInterval(timerRef);
      timerRef = null;
    }
   };
}());
```

And some buttons to make it work (or start it when the page loads):

```
<button onclick="weatherRefresh.start();">Start</button>
<button onclick="weatherRefresh.stop();">Stop</button>
```

Note that the function will only run at **about** every second, if the system is busy it will not run on time and will slowly drift, but not by much each time, so it likely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var timeone = 10;
setInterval(function () {
if (timeone <= 10 && timeone >= 0) { 
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Counting down from " + 
timeone; }
if (timeone == 0) { timeone = 11; }
timeone--;
}, 500);
</script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add a description of your code so readers can not only understand *if* this solves their issue, but also *why* this solves the issue. Answers with a code block and little to no description of the provided code aren't very useful in the sense that it's hard to tell if it actually answers the question.